# WatchKit: The 45mm watch icon is blank

Tags: ios, watchkit

I have added all required icons sizes for the watch app, but the icon for the 45mm watch shows up as blank. The icon shows up properly if I reboot the watch but as soon as I run Xcode and install a new build on the watch, the default icon shows up again.

[image]